# Making sure old marker stay on top

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a function to search the nearby location and make markers appear when click on a default marker. How do I ensure that the same marker would not appear or make sure that the marker does not get cover up by the new marker.

This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fq57xf7e/

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(marker, i) {
     console.log(this.markerDataIndex,this.anotherDataIndex);
       infowindow.setContent(atm[this.markerDataIndex][this.anotherDataIndex][0]);
       infowindow.open(map, this);
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(atm[this.markerDataIndex][this.anotherDataIndex][1], atm[this.markerDataIndex][this.anotherDataIndex][2]));
       map.setZoom(17);
    var man = new google.maps.LatLng(atm[this.markerDataIndex][this.anotherDataIndex][1], atm[this.markerDataIndex][this.anotherDataIndex][2]);
    var request = {
            location: man,
            radius: 200,
            types: ['shopping_mall','store']
          };

         placesList = document.getElementById('places');

          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.nearbySearch(request, callback);



    });
}
}
}

 function callback(results, status, pagination) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    return;
  } else {
    createMarkers(results);

    if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
      var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');

      moreButton.disabled = false;

      google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(moreButton, 'click',
          function() {
        moreButton.disabled = true;
        pagination.nextPage();
      });
    }
  }
}

  function createMarkers(places) {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {


        var tested = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + place.name + '</li>';
      }       
}
```

Comment: Please correct your code in your question. You are missing stuff.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to reproduce the problem?  See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the old markers in front is easy, give the new markers(created in `createMarkers()`) a `zIndex` of `-1`.

to avoid duplicate markers at the same location you may store the "old" markers() in an object.

```
var defaultMarkers={}
```

as property-names use the UrlValue of the marker-position

```
//inside setMarkers, after the creation of the markers in the loop
defaultMarkers[myLatLng.toUrlValue()]=marker;
```

Inside `createMarkers()` check if there is a marker inside `defaultMarkers` whose name is equal to the UrlValue of the place-location, and when not create the new marker

```
if(!defaultMarkers[place.geometry.location.toUrlValue()]){
         var tested = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             title: place.name,
             position: place.geometry.location,
             zIndex:-1
           });
      }
```